# Android: Long click on Action Button

Tags: android, button, action

I want to fire two different functions on an action bar button: one on "click" and another on "long click". To make an example, it should work like a car-radio. where you can store a frequency of a radio channel on a long press and call it on a short press.

The problem is, that you don't really have a custom listener on the action buttons. Google gives:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_compose:
            composeMessage();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to call a listener on long click?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html). Be ware that it must return a boolean meaning that it executed a LongClick or not.

You'll need to add two Listeners on the same Button object:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { ... });
```

Comment: Sorry, but dont get it! Like on the example shown, there are no listeners on MenuItens?!

Comment: So, you are looking for a OnLongClick() for ActionBar buttons? I believe that the ActionBar shouldn't have more functionality that it does, that's why maybe you don't a find an easy solution. Why don't you try restructuring your UI in order to do what you want?

Comment: As @Alxe says Using LongClick on action bar items is not a best solution. However u can create custom views for action bar and implement the same!

Comment: Thanx for feedback! I actually just wanna know, if there is a OnLongClick() possibility or not. Just thought, since you can place buttons on the ActionBar, there must be a way to OnLongClick() them...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom View for action bar and implement the `onLongClick` on the custom View.

Comment: This should be the right way to do it! I took the lazy solution and implemented the first (long click) function in the ActionBarMenu to set my buttons and implented the second function (short click) to call the buttons on the ActionButtons in the ActionBar. Thx!